# Excel Formulas to excel-vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have this formula that looks at various criteria across multiple columns and checks to see that if all the all the criteria match, it will paste data from one column to another. I've tried a couple ways to get it into VBA, but I can't seem to get anything to work. Thanks!

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A$2:A$205,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ECR Approval",Sheet1!$C$2:$C$205)),ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$205)-ROW(Sheet1!$A$2)+1),ROWS(A$2:A2))),"")
```

Comment: "*I can't seem to get anything to work*" is no useful error description as you can imagine. Please show what you already tried. Therefore [edit] your question, add your VBA code and tell where you got stuck or errors and which. It might be useful if you also explain why it is needed to translate it into VBA? I ask for this because there might be an easier alternative if we know more background.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do and what the formula you have written does at the moment. It also helps if you show your data in the spreadsheet so we can see how it is set up.

Answer (score 3):

This is an Array Formula and you can place this formula on the Sheet by using the following code...

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")   'Sheet where formula would be placed
ws.Range("A2").FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A$2:A$205,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""ECR Approval"",Sheet1!$C$2:$C$205)),ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$205)-ROW(Sheet1!$A$2)+1),ROWS(A$2:A2))),"""")"
ws.Range("A2").AutoFill ws.Range("A2:A205"), xlFillDefault
```

Answer (score 1):

To use a function in VBA, you need to use before each function **Application.WorksheetFunction**.

```
x = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(y,z)
```

To reference a cell in a sheet in VBA you can use Rage

```
x = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("A1:A2"))
```

Put this to things Together and it would look like this:

```
=Application.WorksheetFunction.IFERROR(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Worksheet(1).Range("A2:A205"),Application.WorksheetFunction.SMALL(Application.WorksheetFunction.IF(Application.WorksheetFunction.ISNUMBER(....
```